# Icons-only Task Manager Showing Redundant Icons For Dolphin and Firefox

Tags: kubuntu, kde, launcher, task-management

In Kubuntu 19.10, my main display has a panel that features the Icons-only Task Manager widgit. Most icons work the way I want: after clicking an icon, that vary icon becomes my way of returning to that already launched application (when other windows lay atop).

However, when I click the dolphin or firefox icons, a redundant icon (of those application, respectively) gets appended to the Icons-only Task Manager widget and it is that 2nd (redundant) icon that I must use to switch back to that task after other windows have focused in front of it.

Normally, when I right-click on a launcher-icon I have the context-menu option of being able to "unpin that icon", this is not the case with Firefox or Dolphin. Each time I click the dolphin icon, it launches a new window of dolphin instead of switching to the previously launched window of dolphin.

I'm confused as to why these two application's task-manager icons act differently than all the others. To me, there is nothing special about Dolphin or Firefox that I would want them to behave differently than any other launched application.

What setting am I overlooking here? How can I get these two applications to act like all the others: one icon per application and each application is pinable and unpinable?

**Update:** I noticed that my issue was only happening with the default KDE panel (the one that I modified right after install) and was not happening on the panels I created from scratch (for my external monitors).

I fixed the problem by deleting that bad default panel and created a new one from scratch. There may have been a setting I could have changed to fix that default panel, but replacing it is how I fixed it.

**Update 2:** Now, when I hit the super key, it doesn't open the Application Launcher anymore. Consequences! Now what?

Comment: Please add the output of `plasmashell --version`.

Comment: plasmashell 5.16.5 -- See update above. I fixed it.

Comment: The reason I asked about the plasma version is that some users of Kubuntu 19.10 use [a ppa](https://launchpad.net/~kubuntu-ppa/+archive/ubuntu/backports?field.series_filter=eoan) to get the latest version of Plasma, currently 5.18.3.

Comment: I think these two icons are launchers added to the panel, they don't belong to the icons-only-taskmanager which will show only icons for open applications.

Comment: @mook765 : Thanks for pointing that out; I think you're right. Perhaps those Launcher icons are there via the [Quicklaunch Widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XXgx.png).

Comment: @mook765 : No, it is just like you say, they are simply launchers that can be removed by edit panel > remove. If you put that into an answer I'll check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I [discovered](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1225844/) that the default panel doesn't have the icons-only task manger widget by default and that I was really using the default task manager widget (instead of the Icons-Only Task Manger widget).

I fixed this by right-clicking on the default panel, hovering over the Task Manager, selecting "Show Alternatives" (from the hover-context-menu that appeared) and then selected the "Icons-Only Task Manager".